# Dartファイルでのエラー　Error: Entrypoint doesn't contain a main function

Tags: android-studio, flutter

AndroidStudioでDartファイルを実行しようとすると「Edit configuration」という画面が立ち上がり、以下のようなエラーが発生しました。

```
Error: Entrypoint doesn't contain a main function
```

どのように設定するとこのエラーが無くなるのか教えていただけるとうれしいです。

Answer (score 2):

`main`関数がないと言っています。`Dart`はまず`main`関数を探すので必ず書きましょう。

```
void main() {}
```